# Any idea why private property and variable behave differently in FileHelpers?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

To simplify the case, let say I have the following class

```
    public class TestFileHelpersClass
    {
        [FieldOrder(1), FieldFixedLength(20), FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public string Field1 { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(2), FieldFixedLength(20), FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        private string Field2 { get; set; }
        // If change to a normal variable, there is no exception and FileHelper can work perfectly.
        // private string Field2;

        public TestFileHelpersClass()
        {
            this.Field1 = "Field1 Value";
            this.Field2 = "Field2 Value";
        }
    }
```

Then, there is an exception thrown when I instantiate the FileHelperEngine.

```
    static void TestFileHelpers()
    {
        // FileHelpers.BadUsageException: 'The field: '<Field2>k__BackingField' must be marked with the FieldFixedLength attribute because the record class is marked with FixedLengthRecord.'
        FileHelperEngine<TestFileHelpersClass> engine = new FileHelperEngine<TestFileHelpersClass>();

        TestFileHelpersClass a = new TestFileHelpersClass();

        string result = engine.WriteString(new List<TestFileHelpersClass> { a });
    }
```

But {Field2} has already been marked with {FieldFixedLength(20)}

If I change {Field2} from a property to variable, it is working fine.

**The question is:**

When it is public, FileHelpers works perfectly in both the variable and property case.

When it is private, variable is still ok, but property fails to work.

Any idea why private property and variable behave differently in FileHelpers?

Comment: So we go to the GitHub responsible for whichever variant/fork of the library you're using eg [here](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/FileHelpers/Engines/FileHelperEngine.cs), we download the code (button at the top right near clone, let's you do a zip of the whole thing) and we find the exception in it and then look at the conditions that lead to the throw. I often find it handy to have the code of the libs I use for quick debugging and inspection. I'd have done this and posted an answer but I'm on a cellphone and it's a bit more of a pain to do than being on a PC..

Comment: This error is thrown on line 216 of https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/FileHelpers/Fields/FieldBase.cs - if you work it back it'll probably be something like "GetCustomAttributes returns no attribute for a private property" (and then if you look at GetCustomAttributes..)

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for pointing me to the exact code. I guess in FileHelpers, there may be different logics for a property and a variable; otherwise, cannot explain why private variable is working but not private property. Will take a look at the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write autoprops, the compiler generates backing fields for you:

[image]

FileHelpers has *ReflectionHelper.cs* that picks up the *fields* in a type you want it to parse:

[image]

This means, for my dumb class in the first screenshot, it will pick up the two __BackingField, and the two normally named fields:

[image]

When FileHelpers is processing these in *FieldBase.cs*, for any backing fields that have a friendly name, it goes for the property:

[image]

`fi` is the __BackingField; it does have a friendly name because it's come from PrivateProp. To go for the property, FH calls this:

```
var prop = fi.DeclaringType.GetProperty(fieldFriendlyName);
```

This call *won't* discover a private property because it doesn't specify any `BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance`, so `prop` ends up `null` and FH doesn't switch to looking at the property

Look back at the first image; the FileHelper custom attributes are on the property, not the backing field. Later in this same *FieldBase.cs* class, FH tries to find derivates of its own attributes (FH's attributes derive from `FieldAttribute`) on the member being inspected:

[image]

The member being inspected is the __BackingField, which doesn't have any FH attributes; it's the *prop* that has the attributes. The field does have attributes (CompilerGenerated, DebuggerBrowsable) but because this call looks only for *FH's attributes* and the backing field doesn't have any FH custom attributes it is essentially looking on the wrong thing. It reaches a situation where it cannot work - it needs attributes you've put on the prop, but it looks on the field, finds no FH attribs and throws an error because it needs those attributes it can never find.

---

If `fi.DeclaringType.GetProperty(fieldFriendlyName)` had instead used an overload that looked for private props e.g. `fi.DeclaringType.GetProperty(fieldFriendlyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|..other_binding_flags_here)` then it would have found the private prop you decorated (but I don't guarantee that this is a bug or that that is the resolution)

You could report a bug and see if the author agrees, you could amend the library yourself and use the amended version, or you could just use fields/public props instead of private props

---

I cannot answer *why* the library was coded this way; few people here can. Questions of the ilk "what was developer X thinking when..." are seldom a good fit for SO.

Comment: Thanks for the great details. You not only points out where is the exception but also the code path how it cannot work. Simply speaking, it is getting NonPublic fields (GetFields) first, and checks if there is a corresponding "Public" Property (GetProperty) with the FileHelpers attributes, that is why a private Property fails but a public one succeeds. It is weird to me that it gets all private fields (even it is not a backing fields), but for property, it just gets the public ones. But I agree that it is a question difficult to answer.

Comment: Yep, that's the short version- get all fields, then only get related public properties. You could ask a question on FileHelpers GitHub if you want to know why; you're certain to reach the author that way